# Div's visibility with javascript - problem

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use div's to display content on my page. This is controlled with an onchange element in a select menu. It works perfectly but the problem is I want one div to close when another one is opened. The div's open fine but it does not close the others. An example code is below. What am I doing wrong?

JavaScript:

```
if(document.getElementById('catgry').value == '01'){
    document.getElementById('post04').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('post04').style.display = "";

    document.getElementById('post07').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('post07').style.display = "none";
}else if(document.getElementById('catgry').value == '02'){
    document.getElementById('post02').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('post02').style.display = "";

    document.getElementById('post04').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('post04').style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById('post07').style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('post07').style.display = "none";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="post04" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;">
  <table  class="posttb"><tr>
    <td width="30%">Author</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="author" size="30" class="postfd"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

 </div>
```

Comment: You could simplify the issue by putting the display rules in CSS and just adding and removing classes to your divs.

Comment: @sammville Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Tx7g/

Comment: No you *do not* need to use jQuery. But your current approach is pretty inefficient. It would be easier to know the best approach if we had a more complete picture of your HTML. Are the `post0x` elements siblings? If so, does their parent container have an ID?

Comment: +1 to "patrick dw"... why does everything should always be done with jQuery? jQuery is _not_ god in the javascript world...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I see that you're trying to question jQuery's role as the god in the JavaScript world. [You should totally drop that and use jQuery.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)

Comment: I am not trying, I am saying. Thats my opinion but I never, and will never say, that jQuery isn't a valid answer for 90% of all Javascript questions. I just asked: why is it "always" jQuery... read the Javascript questions here... everyone should use jQuery... what about the educational effect of "do it by yourself" instead of "use the library function x"... anyway this is a discussion without a right or wrong, so I feel relieved and thats good for my blood pressure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing your markup, but it could be as simple as this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jtfke/

```
var posts = document.getElementById('posts').children;

document.getElementById('catgry').onchange = function() {
    for( var i = 0, len = posts.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        posts[ i ].style.display = (i == this.selectedIndex) ? 'block' : '';
    }
};
```

*example html*

```
<select id='catgry'>
    <option value='post01'>post 1</option>
    <option value='post02'>post 2</option>
    <option value='post03'>post 3</option>
    <option value='post04'>post 4</option>
</select>
<div id='posts'>
    <div>post 1 content</div>
    <div>post 2 content</div>
    <div>post 3 content</div>
    <div>post 4 content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pure JS is definitely better for troubleshooting code. jQuery is just compounding the problem by adding 50+ KB of unneeded code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using jQuery and the jQuery accordion
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: @sammville Well, what JavaScript library are you using then?

Comment: I am not using any library for it. The javascript code i wrote for it is above

Comment: @sammville is there a reason you don't want to use a javascript library?

Comment: No!! just thought coding it would be easier. Any recommendation of libraries to use?

Comment: @sammville jQuery, easy to use and there is a large collection of plugins, check out @Sime's jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9Tx7g/

Comment: why does everything should always be done with jQuery? jQuery is not god in the javascript world...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with pure Javascript and some looping.

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <select id="selectMenu">
        <option id="option1" value="option 1">option 1</option>
        <option id="option2" value="option 2">option 2</option>
        <option id="option3" value="option 3">option 3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="div1" class="postDiv">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="postDiv">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="postDiv">Div 3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
init();


function init()
{
    addListeners();  
}

function addListeners()
{
    document.getElementById("selectMenu").onchange = selectChange;
}

function selectChange(evt)
{
    for(var i=0;i<evt.currentTarget.length;i++)
    {
        if(i == evt.currentTarget.selectedIndex)
        {
          adjustDivs(i+1, evt.currentTarget.options);
        }  
    }
}

function adjustDivs(optionId, options)
{
    document.getElementById("div" + optionId).style.display = "block";
    for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++)
    {
        if(i != (optionId-1))
        {
            document.getElementById("div" + (i+1)).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hGxfS/

Answer (score 0):

Install jquery;

Use this code as html markup for select box . remember to specify id=visibiitySelector and providean attribute "_showelement" for each option value, that matches with the id of the div you want to display if option is selected

```
<select id="visibilitySelector">
    <option value="whatever" _showelement="post01">whatever</option>
    <option value="whatever" _showelement="post02">whatever</option>
</select>
```

Copy this function into the javascripts of the page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#visibilitySelector').change(function(){
        var showelement = $('#visibilitySelector option:selected').attr('_showelement');
        $('div.showhide').not('#' + showelement ).hide();
        $('#' + showelement ).show();
    });
});
```

Code the divs as below, remembering to provide class "showhide"

```
<div id="post01" class="showhide">
</div>
<div id="post01" class="showhide">
</div>
<div id="post01" class="showhide">
</div>
```